# How to set an enum value on a dynamic Odata object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an ODATA service that returns a dynamic object similar to this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/leohu/2013/11/04/typeless-entity-object-support-in-webapi/

When I am populating the objects properties, I do:

```
 var entityCategory = new EdmEntityObject(entityType);
 bool bSuccess = entityCategory.TrySetPropertyValue("Name", "Category 1");
```

And this works fine, but I am unable to set the value of any of my Enum properties. Here's what I've tried:

```
var edmValue= new EdmEnumValue( new EdmEnumTypeReference( enumType, true ), value );
bool bSuccess = entityCategory.TrySetProperty( "Status", edmValue );
```

But that doesn't work and I simply get null in the response. `bSuccess` is `true`, and it even has the expected value if I call `TryGetValue` afterwards.

However, in the web response status still shows as NULL.

I've tried a bunch of variations, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

### **FOUND SOLUTION**

HERE is what eventually worked for me:

```
var oEnumObject = new EdmEnumObject( enumType, strEnumValue );
entity.TrySetPropertyValue( fieldName, oEnumObject );
```

Not sure why I need to use EdmEnumObject, but it appears to work. It actually will accept and display any string value for strEnumValue.

### NONE OF THIS WORKS

Some more info:

When I add an enum to the datamodel I do something like:

```
var enumType = new EdmEnumType( Namespace, "Status", EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int64, false);
enumType.AddMember( "Active", 0);
..
AddProperty( EdmStructuralProperty( this, field.Name, new EdmEnumTypeReference( thisEnum, bIsNullable ) )
```

I cache the value of `enumType` here, and use it later when I am populating ( in the code above ). Therefore, I think `enumType` is valid. As for `value`, I had some code to pick the correct `EdmEnumMember`, but I've also just tried hard coding it to the first in the list and it still comes out as `null`:

```
var edmValue = new EdmEnumValue( new EdmEnumTypeReference( enumType, true ), enumType.Members.First() );
```

So what the heck? I've hit a breakpoint there and it appears to have the correct value, but I get null in the response. I've also tried this:

```
var value = new ODataEnumValue( nEnumIntValue.ToString(), enumType.FullName() );
entity.TrySetPropertyValue( col.ColumnName, value );
```

Again, NULL. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You are missing some variables that could prove helpful. Show your declaration of `enumType` and `value`.

Comment: Added some more code..happy to answer any other questions

Answer (score 2):

Referencing the [following test on github](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/cae9bbb85b5a45cc03dc42eec84f5e9eb1a41ed9/test/FunctionalTests/Tests/DataEdmLib/FunctionalTests/EdmValueKindTests.cs#L298) foe `EdmEnumType`

You should take a look at how you are creating and adding the members to the `enumType`...

```
//make sure you enum type is not nullable
var enumType = new EdmEnumType(Namespace, "Status", EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetInt32(false).PrimitiveDefinition(), false);

//enum members are made up of constants
var enumMember = enumType.AddMember("Active", new EdmIntegerConstant(0));

//You should also not make the value nullable
var edmValue = new EdmEnumValue(new EdmEnumTypeReference(enumType, false), enumMember);
```

Comment: Thank you for assistance, I eventually figured it out. Not sure if your answer helped, but it at least gave me the will to try again.